# Flutter: How to show Ios incoming call not showing when the app is in background?

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, callkit, flutter-ios

I have implemented a video call and I use [callkeep](https://pub.dev/packages/callkeep) to show incoming call notifications. when I received a call invitation from agora_rtm engine.

It shows incoming call notifications when the app is in foreground. but when I minimize the app, I see the log. but not showing the incoming call screen.

It works fine for android.

How to show callkeep incoming call when the app is minimized?